# How to iterate through a set of heterogeneous elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to iterate through a few HTML  elements and get their values. I tried using `$.each()` for this but I can't figure out how to do it when an element has other elements of variable types inside it. I have the HTML DOM structure as  :

```
<li>
 <div>X</div>
 <br/>
 <span>Category : </span>
 <div>Y</div>
 <span><br/>Rating</span>
 <div>
 <span>Z</span>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the values `X , Y , Z` from it. Also there are multiple instances of this so I will have to iterate through each of them. Can anyone suggest some approach to this?

Comment: Why not give each element you are interested in an ID (or a class) and then select by ID/class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: `div` is not allowed inside `li`. Just sayin'

Comment: @Prinzhorn ok I'm not very good with this but I'm pretty sure `div` is allowed inside `li`.

Comment: @Aneesh you are right. sorry for the wasted time.

Comment: Check my updated anser

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are reading the `text` content of all `div` elements within the `li`. So try

```
$('li').children('div').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: But "Z" is in a span...although I s'pose that span is inside a div.

Comment: @nnnnnn it looks like the span is wrapped in a div

Answer (score 1):

Assign the elements you are interested in to a `class`:

```
<li>
 <div class="value">X</div>
 <br/>
 <span>Category : </span>
 <div class="value">Y</div>
 <span><br/>Rating</span>
 <div>
 <span class="value">Z</span>
</div>
```

Then select values by class:

```
$('.values').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
$('li > div').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
})
```

-EDIT-

If you don't want any content inside those spans, you could try:

```
$('li > div').each(function(){
      var $tmp =  $(this).clone();
      $tmp.find('span').remove();
      console.log($tmp.text());

})
```